# What is wrong with this nested SELECT statement compared to the one that works?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am using the AP database distributed by Microsoft. This works:

```
USE AP
SELECT V.VendorName, InvoiceDate, InvoiceTotal
FROM Invoices I 
INNER JOIN Vendors V ON I.VendorID = V.VendorID
WHERE InvoiceTotal > 
    (SELECT AVG(InvoiceTotal)
     FROM Invoices)
ORDER BY InvoiceTotal
```

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT AP.dbo.Invoices.InvoiceTotal, AP.dbo.Vendors.VendorName, AP.dbo.Invoices.InvoiceDate
FROM     AP.dbo.Invoices INNER JOIN
                  AP.dbo.Vendors ON AP.dbo.Invoices.VendorID = AP.dbo.Vendors.VendorID
WHERE  AP.dbo.Invoices.InvoiceTotal >
                      (SELECT AVG(AP.dbo.Invoices.InvoiceTotal) AS Expr1
                       FROM      AP.dbo.Invoices AS Invoices_1)
```

The error I get on the above query is this:

> Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: Have table aliases for both AP.dbo.Invoices... Since you have renamed the subquery AP.dbo.Invoices, the column in AVG() belongs to the other AP.dbo.Invoices table instance.

Answer (score 3):

Use table aliases!

```
SELECT i.InvoiceTotal, v.VendorName, i.InvoiceDate
FROM AP.dbo.Invoices i INNER JOIN
     AP.dbo.Vendors v
     ON i.VendorID = v.VendorID
WHERE i.InvoiceTotal > (SELECT AVG(i2.InvoiceTotal)
                        FROM AP.dbo.Invoices i2
                       );
```

Your code doesn't work because the subquery is not referring to the table in the subquery.  That would be `invoice_1.InvoiceTotal` rather than what you have.  The reference to the outer query is not allowed with an aggregation function.

Comment: @nicomp did this answer your question?